# How to make sidebar menu aligns to left margin of body?

Tags: html, css

My layout is mobile-only, so the body max-width is 700px, I have a sidebar menu that I want to align with the left margin of the body, currently it aligns with the viewport, so if the viewport is bigger than 700px the sidebar opens from the left margin of the viewport, outside the rest of the content. How can I make it aligned to the body, regardless of the screen size?

```css
.burger-menu {
  width: 0;
  background-color: var(--lightest-grey);
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  left: 0;
  transition: width 0.7s ease-out;
}

.menu-active {
  width: calc(var(--max-width) * 0.7);
  display: flex;
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-sea-wfnxk?file=/style.css:1949-2021

Answer (score 0):

Your `.burger-menu` is absolutely positioned with `left: 0`. Absolute positioning is relative to the nearest positioned ancestor element, so set its parent element with `position: relative`.

```
nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  width: 100%;
  /* ---------- changes ---------- */
  /* overflow-x: scroll; */
  position: relative;
  /* ---------- changes ---------- */
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
  scrollbar-width: none;
  background-color: var(--medium-grey);
  justify-content: space-between;
  min-height: 2.5em;
}
.burger-menu {
  width: 0;
  background-color: var(--lightest-grey);
  /* ---------- changes ---------- */
  /* height: 100%; */
  height: 100vh;
  /* ---------- changes ---------- */
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  left: 0;
  transition: width 0.7s ease-out;
}
```